# Can't make React-Router render two different components, always render root

Tags: javascript, routes, react-router, reactjs

I have these two components that are completely independent of each other. I want to render `App` when I enter `/` and render `About` when I go to `/#/about`

I got this piece of code (but I tested quite a few others):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import App from './App';
import About from './About';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App} >
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I also tried something like

```
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
<Route path="/" component={App} />
```

And changed /about to `/#/about`, `about`

But it always render the "fallback" `/`, it always goes to this route, no matter what.

How can I make this app navigate properly to `/` and `/about` and render the `App` and the `About` components?

**@edit**

Assuming that my About component is broken, I removed the first `Route` and kept only the `/about` (kept only the `/about` Route) :

```
<Route path="/about" component={App} />
```

(I tried keeping About as well in a previous test) and also changed the `/about` to `about` and `/#/about`.

And I get this error on console:

> "VM3651 bundle.js:30801 Warning: [react-router] Location "/#/about" did not match any routes"

**@edit 2**

I made a change, following the example @Dominic posted. I had to make some modifications to make sure both components would render. I added the {this.props.children} to all Components to understand what would happen.

```
//imports
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={About} >
    <IndexRoute component={App} />
    <Route path="/about" component={Other} />
  </Route>
</Router>
,document.getElementById('root'));
```

The route `http://localhost:3000/#/about` is rendering:

> > About > App

So it is rendering the IndexRoute, it is not getting caught by the `/about`.

And this is now exactly what I need, because I didn't want a root component, I wanted 2 routes to 2 different and isolated components. I need something like two sibling routes.

**@edit**

The About.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class About extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        About page
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

**Solution:**

Since I'm using a HASH (#) in the URL, I should use `hashHistory` from React Router in the `<Router history={hashHistory}>`

Comment: the only difference i note from https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router here is just the fact that they use render(( .....), document.getElement....); while you are using only 1 (), i cant believe thats the reason but well who knows

Comment: can you show your about component?

Comment: How you redirect to about page? <Link to="/about" />? Or manually typing URL? You're using the browserHistory so hash shouldnt exist in the url :)

Comment: I use the # (hash) in the url (see new edit). So I should go to `http://localhost:3000/about` ? The webpack server is responding "Cannot GET /about"

Comment: with `hashHistory` this works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing how routes work - `About` is a child of the `App` route, so in order to render `About`, it has to render `App`.

In other words your `App` component is the "shell" and all components under it render INSIDE it (via `props.children`).

You should add another route to render `/`.

```
import { ..., IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

<Route path="/" component={App} >
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  <Route path="about" component={About} />
</Route>
```

Your `App` does not contain route specific content, it would be something more like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <nav>app navigation</nav>
  <main class="route-content">{props.children}</main>
</div>
```

Docs: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#adding-an-index

Comment: but in the top of that page , they are showing the first version of the app, without the index route, and it says that the app already knows how to render / and /about , without the indexRoute. http://imgur.com/a/yOKuh

Comment: if you look at that image / renders App, and the others render App and the component which is expected

Answer (score 0):

Those routes look correct to me.  Are you getting any errors in the console? Maybe your About component is undefined and thus not rendering.  Can you post your About component?

Comment: Assuming that my About component is broken, I removed the first `Route` and kept only the /about: 

`<Route path="/about" component={App} />` (I tried keeping About as well in a previous test) and also changed the `/about` to `about` and `/#/about`.

And I get this error on console: "VM3651 bundle.js:30801 Warning: [react-router] Location "/#/about" did not match any routes"

Comment: Just as a test put your About component on your "/"  route

Comment: And just for reference "/about"  is the correct route

Comment: Can you still post it here?